PHP-FPM: Processes open but never close nor become idle
We use php-fpm for our website with significant traffic around this time of the year.
Because there are many requests we tend to encounter some slowdown and 504 errors.
Yet we have a fairly solid php-fpm config:
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 266
pm.start_servers = 66
pm.min_spare_servers = 66
pm.max_spare_servers = 199

However when I start the php-fpm service I immediately see it filled up with child processes, maxing out at ~260 processes almost immediately.
When I executed fpm_get_status after an hour or two I see such information as this :
    "pool": "www",
    "process-manager": "dynamic",
    "start-time": 1724668195,
    "start-since": 9420,
    "accepted-conn": 76026,
    "listen-queue": 346,
    "max-listen-queue": 512,
    "listen-queue-len": 511,
    "idle-processes": 0,
    "active-processes": 266,
    "total-processes": 266,
    "max-active-processes": 266,
    "max-children-reached": 2,
    "slow-requests": 0,

Here's an example of a process among the 260 fpm processes:
        {
            "pid": 3246916,
            "state": "Running",
            "start-time": 1724671716,
            "start-since": 5899,
            "requests": 198,
            "request-duration": 32144904,
            "request-method": "GET",
            "request-uri": "/index.php",
            "query-string": "page_id=150",
            "request-length": 0,
            "user": "-",
            "script": "/app/application/index.php",
            "last-request-cpu": 0,
            "last-request-memory": 0
        },

So none of the processes are considered "idle", they're just running forever even though PHP does have max_execution_time.
When the server is not under heavy load, the processes become idle correctly :
    "pool": "www",
    "process-manager": "dynamic",
    "start-time": 1724668195,
    "start-since": 13484,
    "accepted-conn": 111033,
    "listen-queue": 0,
    "max-listen-queue": 512,
    "listen-queue-len": 511,
    "idle-processes": 197,
    "active-processes": 2,
    "total-processes": 199,
    "max-active-processes": 266,
    "max-children-reached": 2,
    "slow-requests": 0,

So it works correctly under normal circumstances but under heavy load php-fpm does not close "zombie processes".
For me a process simply meant to display a page should not be in a Running state for nearly an hour (start-since: 5899)
My question(s):

Is dynamic correct for a website with lots of visitors? Should I not switch to ondemand to use pm.process_idle_timeout?
Is there a configuration item in PHP-FPM that can force-kill old processes like the one in the example above?


Did you find a solution? I believe I'm experiencing the same issue.
